# Refresh Telerik MVC Grid with Ajax Call, after Success call a Function?

Tags: jquery, telerik-grid

I see there are lot of related question in this site. But Still I am not able to make this work for my requirement.

This is my ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/Medication/StopMedication",
      data: { ID: pid, StopNote: note },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function () {
           refreshGrid()
      }
});
```

and my refresh grid is like this

```
  function refreshGrid() {
        alert("I am at Refresh Grid");
        if ($(".t-grid .t-refresh").exists()) {
            $(".t-grid .t-refresh").trigger('click');
        }
    }
```

First of all after success my ajax call is not firing refreshGrid() function.
can any one help me with this

I found the issue and fixed it:

---

**I Made these Changes**

```
 dataType: "text",
  success: function (data) {
       refreshGrid();
  }

 function refreshGrid() {
   $(".t-grid .t-refresh").trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function refreshGrid() {
        $(".t-grid .t-refresh").trigger('click');
   }
```

This worked or me

Answer (score 4):

to reload the grid use this after success ajax call

> var optionsGrid = $("#favorite-grid"); //you grid ID
>
> optionsGrid.data('tGrid').ajaxRequest();

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You need to troubleshoot first why the success callback is not invoked. Perhaps there is an error. You can try handling the `error` of [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to see what the response is. You can also use some HTTP sniffing tool (WebKit's developer tools, [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/)) to inspect what the server response is.

When you sort out the success handler not being invoked you can use the [ajaxRequest](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#ajaxRequest) method of the grid to refresh it.

Comment: I could fix my problem. please check the solution i have updated on top

Answer (score 0):

In this way

```
   function refreshGrid() {
        $(".t-grid .t-refresh").trigger('click');
   }
```

it would refresh all of your grids on your page, if you have more than one grid. Even the detail grids will be refreshed.

To prevent this you can use the Id of your grid

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("myGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ContactName).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress);
        columns.Bound(o => o.OrderDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(120);
    })
..........
..........
..........
)

   function refreshGrid() {
        $("myGrid .t-grid .t-refresh").trigger('click');
   }
```

Comment: that's true, in my case i am having only one grid in a page and I use this refreshGrid() as a generalized function to call it when ever i need to refresh.

Comment: In this case you can pass a parameter function refreshGrid(myGrid) {
        $("#" + myGrid + " .t-grid .t-refresh").trigger('click');
   }

Comment: Good. definitely Much Better way

Answer (score 0):

For Server Bindings Telerik Grid Just need to do the following Thing..... Just use and cheers

After any event you can call this

```
 var href = $('.t-refresh').attr('href');
 window.location.href = href;
```